# How can I push to bitbucket.org without my project parent directory

Tags: bitbucket, egit

I had created a remote repo with bitbucket.org, for example, https://somebody@bitbucket.org/somebody/test.git

When I pushed my local repo to the bitbucket repo by Eclipse EGit, I got all my project files in a parent directory, for example, https://somebody@bitbucket.org/somebody/test.git/Test/XXX. But I only hoped all my project files located in the repo root, for example, https://somebody@bitbucket.org/somebody/test.git/XXXX.

How can I do? Thanks!

Comment: Where is the root of the git repo (that is, the directory containing the `.git` directory) relative to the `Test` directory?

Comment: thanks for your reply, my local files layout is as following:      test/.git, test/Test

Answer (score 0):

eGit converts eclipse project into a folder under your Git repo when you 'share' it. **This is the way eGit works**, so I don't think what you asking is possible with eGit.

It is better this way IMO because such design allows for several projects in the same Git repository, which is very common.